# Binding d3 table to Backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, d3.js

So I've tried

```
        @table =    d3.select("#search-results-area").append("table").attr("id","resultsTable").attr("class","visualization-panel")
        @thead = @table.append("thead")
        @tbody = @table.append("tbody")
        @thead.append("tr").selectAll("th").data(@columns).enter().append("th").text((col)-> return col).on("click",(d)=>@tbody.selectAll("tr").sort(@sortingFunctionManager[d]))
        @tbody.selectAll("tr").attr("class","spacing center-text")
            console.log "tbody"
       console.log 
       @rows = @tbody.selectAll("tr").data(@collection.models).append("tr")
       console.log @rows
       console.log @collection.models
       cells = @rows.selectAll("td").data((model)=>
       console.log "inside callback"
       console.log model
        return @columns.map((column)=>
            return { column : column, val : model.get(column)}
            )
        ).enter().append("td").text((d)=> 
            console.log "what is d"
            console.log d
            for column in @columns
                if d.column == column
                    return d.val
        )
```

The cells won't append. In fact, there are no trs

Comment: -1 What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In d3, when you bind a dataset using .data, the data is cross-correlated against the nodes in the DOM you're binding to, and you end up with 3 groups:

The `.enter()` group which represents new elements in the dataset that do not have corresponding nodes in the DOM

The `.exit()` group which represents elements in the DOM that do not have corresponding elements in the dataset

and everything else - which represents elements in the dataset that DO have corresponding elements in the DOM.

In your case, you need to operate on the `.enter()` elements - new data, and tell d3 to generate new nodes in the DOM for those items.

In a 2D table, you need to do this twice - once for each new model, which generates a row, and once for each new property on the model (for each row), which represents a TD cell.

For the rows, it looks like this:

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    // The function returns an identity value for the model
    //   - otherwise its just correlated by position
    .data(myCol.models,function(d){return d.cid})
    // Ok, for any new models, add a TR to the table
    .enter()
        .append("tr");
```

for the data cells:

```
var cell = rows.selectAll("td")
    // D3 is expecting an array of values, you'll probably want to 
    //  generate this using your "columns" array
    //  the data value (d) is the Backbone model bound to each row
    .data(function(d) { return [d.get('id'),d.get('name')] })
    // For each property ([id, name])append a TD cell
    .enter().append("td")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Hopefully, this should get you started.

Here's a working jsFiddle to play with, that shows this behavior (and more):

http://jsfiddle.net/3SgnA/2/

Comment: yeah, I just figured this out! I'll accept it though, as it's correct.